# Editing CodeBlocks WxSmiths project

Tags: wxwidgets, codeblocks

I have an old project done in CodeBlocks WxSmiths. I copied it across to my new computer and now I cannot make any changes to the project! I can add items to a panel on the main frame (and the preview looks fine) but the changes are discarded when I compile and run the project. All I get is the old project executable without my new additions! (I did clean build as well). Or in other words a main frame cpp file and header file is not getting updated with the new changes I make to the form. The files are not read-only. Do anybody have any ideas as why this happens?

Comment: IF you want the changes not to be discarded write your code and place it in the **Extra Code** field in the Frames **Property window**.That will work..Try it out!!

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Vasanth,
I myself can edit the frame main cpp file and it stays and compiles fine. The problem is, I cannot add any new items on the form, nor can I add any new event handlers (say, "OnCheckBox1Click"). It says "Couldn't add new handlers"!. Code blocks should have automatically update the frame main cpp and header files when I add / delete items on the form, or when I add event handlers. This is not happening in my case!

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is the case when you have wxSmith files pointing to incorrect source files.
Open the project file (using your favorite editor) and check the **Extensions** xml tag:

```
<Extensions>
    <code_completion />
    <debugger />
    <wxsmith version="1">
        <gui name="wxWidgets" src="src/wxExampleApp.cpp" main="wxExample" init_handlers="necessary" language="CPP" />
        <resources>
            <wxPanel wxs="wxsmith/somePanel.wxs" src="src/somePanel.cpp" hdr="src/somePanel.h" name="windowTabPanel" language="CPP" />
        </resources>
    </wxsmith>
    <envvars />
</Extensions>
```

Make sure that your src and hdr files point to the correct source files you have in your project.
Otherwise wxSmith won't be able to update those files based on the changes made from the RAD view.