# Main program doesn't reflect wxsmith frame changes anymore in CodeBlocks

Tags: wxwidgets, codeblocks

I'm facing exactly the same situation as in the following thread:
[Editing CodeBlocks WxSmiths project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521955/editing-codeblocks-wxsmiths-project?answertab=oldest#tab-top).
I can make changes to mywxframe.wxs but they are not taken into account at compile time. When I rebuild the main program, all the wx widgets remain as if there had been no change. 
What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I had moved the project, myProject.cbp had to be edited manually, unfortunately this file does only handle paths relative to itself and ignores absolute ones. Lots of time spent for almost nothing.

Comment: Where did you change that? I have the same problem and it's pretty annoying.